# Komodo: Change Default File Preferences

Tags: komodo, komodoedit

In Komodo, I can change file preferences by right clicking on the file and going to File Preferences. Is there a way to change the default file preferences any time I open a new file?

Komodo edit 11.1.0 mac

Answer (score 0):

You can set some defaults under *Edit menu > Preferences > [ File Opening | Syntax & Spell Checking | Languages ]*.